# How to solve form validation on flutter error: Closure call with mismatched arguments

Tags: flutter, validation, textformfield

While trying to follow the videos, I learnt that the validate is anonymous function and will give you value and then you should do operations on that value, but there's something off for me; I don't know what causes the error:

```
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>'Receiver: Closure: (dynamic) => String?Tried calling: _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>()Found: _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>(dynamic) => String?
```

This is how I write my code to show the widget:

```
defaultFormField(
    onChanged: (){},
    emailController: emailController,
  validate: (value){
      if(value==null||value.isEmpty){
        return 'please enter your email';
      }
      else {
        return null;
      }
  },
  prefixIcon: Icons.email,
    labelText: 'Email',
),
```

and this is the `defaultFormField` implementation:

```
{
  required Function onChanged,
  required TextEditingController emailController,
  bool obscureText=false,
  IconData? suffixIcon,
  required Function validate,
  required IconData prefixIcon,
  required String labelText,
}
){
  return
  TextFormField(
  onChanged: onChanged(),
keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
controller: emailController,
obscureText: obscureText,
decoration: InputDecoration(
border: OutlineInputBorder(),
prefixIcon: Icon(prefixIcon),
labelText: labelText,
  suffixIcon: suffixIcon !=null ? Icon(suffixIcon):null,
),
validator: validate(),

);
}
```

Comment: `validator: validate()` should be `validator: validate`, or you'll be invoking the function at the wrong level.